# Improved way to find out "unused" values in SELECT WHERE IN statement

Tags: mysql

I have written a simple SQL query which looks like this:

```
Select * from tableName where tableId IN (id1,id2,id3....idN)
```

The query works just fine. My question is: Is there any quick way to find out which of the id[1-N] were NOT found in the result set? I know I can iterate through the result of the query and compare it with the IDs I passed in the query, but I hope there is a quicker way than that.

Comment: I'm assuming that `tableName` in the query example is storing a transaction type data whereby the `id` value might not be present or might be repeated. Is this correct? If it is, do you have a table that only specifically store `id` regardless if the `id` have transaction data or not?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a left join base

```
  select id from  (
    select id1 id
    union 
    select id2
    union 
    select id3
    ....
    union 
    select idN 
  ) t 
  left join  tableName a on a.tableId = t.id 
  where a.tableId is null
```

(if the values for id1 ... idN is a result for a subquery you could use the subquery instead of select union)